# Simple Java Compile Error on Mac: Trying to use Scanner Class for data input at command prompt?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Java for the first time on my Mac (OS X 10.6.8).  A simple "Hello World" example works fine.  However, now I'm trying to input data via command prompts and compilation fails on syntax, expecting a semicolon.  Code comes from the book: "Java Programming: From Problem Analysis to Program Design", 5th Edition, by D.S. Malik.

The compilation error is:

```
javac Example2_17.java
Example2_17.java:18: ';' expected
    firstName console.next();
                     ^
1 error
```

The java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-10M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

The java code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example2_17
{

  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    int age;
    double weight;

    System.out.println("Enter first name, last name, age, and weight separated by spaces.");

    firstName console.next(); // <----------- ERROR HERE!
    //lastName console.next();
    //age console.nextIng();
    //weight console.nextDouble();

    //System.out.println("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

    //System.out.println("Age: " + age);
    //System.out.println("Weight: " + weight);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note. In Java, the convention is to declare variables as late as possible, only when needed: `String firstName = console.next();`. No need to declare all the bariables at the top of the method like in Pascal or C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an assignment operator `=`

```
firstName = console.next();
```

Without the operator the compiler considers the statement a declaration so complains when it doesn't find `;` at the expected location.

Comment: Oh Geeze!  I need sleep.  I stared at that code for an hour and kept thinking it was something with my installation that was the issue.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing an equal sign after firstName.

Is..

```
firstName console.next();
```

Should be...

```
firstName = console.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use try and catch statements.There must be an exception or use throwIOException. There is another error /age console.nextIng(); you added an Ing intstead of int and that may be another cause of your error.You have also forgotten the "=" operater to store the data extracted into your local variable.`